# How to run back batch file commands from command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In my web application i run some background process with database and java executable jar files for performing operation using text files. So i decided to write batch command to run by task scheduler.

I have written a batch file command and run its successfully. But inside batch command i am calling the another command file like **StartImportGroup.cmd**.

During the batch file running, the command call perform the action in some loop, after finishing the operation it exit the whole batch file process also.

How to back to run the remaining batch commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a batch file to call another batch file and return batch, put the word CALL in front of the inner batch file.

```
CALL StartImportGroup.cmd
```

Otherwise, control switches over to the second batch file, but never returns when the second batch file ends.